# How to use a List<T> in place of ArrayList here?

Tags: c#, arraylist, generic-list

Have been hearing all around ArrayList getting obsolete these days. But I do have a genuine case to use an ArrayList, like this:

```
    ArrayList GetArrayInt()
    {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.Add(2);

        return l;
    }

    ArrayList GetArrayBool()
    {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.Add(true);

        return l;
    }

    void Process(ArrayList l)
    {
        foreach (var o in l)
        {
            if (o is int)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Then I call `Process` like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process(GetArrayInt());
        //or
        Process(GetArrayBool());
    }
```

The bottom line is I dont need to write two `Process` methods separately for an ArrayList of ints and bools.

But I hear all negatives about ArrayLists. So I wanna implement it using `List<T>`. This is what I come up with:

```
    List<bool> GetListBool()
    {
        var l = new List<bool>();
        l.Add(true);

        return l;
    }

    List<int> GetListInt()
    {
        var l = new List<int>();
        l.Add(2);

        return l;
    }

    void Process(List<object> l)
    {
        foreach (var o in l)
        {
            if (o is int)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Now how do I call it?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process(GetListInt()); //error
        Process(GetListBool()); //error
        Process((List<object>)GetListBool()); //error
    }
```

The only solution here I found is to write separate `Process` methods for `List<bool>` and `List<int>` which is then two methods (my actual code is a lot more complex, so going by this approach I will need to write twenty such `Process` methods all which do the same thing).

How can I go about writing just one `Process` method in `List<T>` approach? Can `List<T>` replace an ArrayList even here?

**Update:** all the three answers work, but I liked @Phil's answer the best. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Gravell says, what your doing is odd, but you could use type inference and use `Process<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` if you want to:

```
void Main()
{
    Process(GetInts());
    Process(GetBools());
}

IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
{
    return new List<int>{1,2,3};
}

IEnumerable<bool> GetBools()
{
    return new List<bool>{true, false, true};
}

void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if(item is int)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("int: " + item.ToString());
        }
        if(item is bool)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("bool: " + item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The more sensible way that doesn't require `if(item is int)` etc  would be to have an overload of Process for each type

```
void Process(IEnumerable<int> items) { foreach(...) };
void Process(IEnumerable<bool> items) { foreach(...) };
```

Comment: No, not in 2.0, co-variance is 4.0 onwards.

Comment: This isn't covariance... It is just generic type inference. So (@nawfal) it should work fine in 2.0. Covariance relates to the transparent assignment from `IWhatever<Foo>` to `IWhatever<Bar>` for related Foo/Bar

Answer (score 3):

It is an odd example, and isn't very OOP, but: you could indeed use `List<int>`, `List<bool>`, etc - and change the return type / parameter type to the non-generic `IList` or `IEnumerable`. Odd example though.

Comment: seeing my requirement, what is a more OOP solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to convert a type-safe list to `List<object>`:

```
List<object> objList = GetListBool().Cast<object>().ToList();
```